# How do I set up and push a repo to github?

Tags: git, github

I have git and git-core installed on my Linux Ubuntu 10.10 server in order to compile a server that I have. I set everything up following the tutorial on the github site, but when I do the git remote add origin , I get the following error

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Disk quota exceeded
```

I have tried under both the server's user and the root user. I continued with trying to push the repo and got the same message on all of the next steps. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and still got the error.

For note: I did not set up any quota when I purchased this Linux Server.

Thanks ahead.

Edit: Looks like all my inodes are consumed. I'm deleting files to regain those inodes.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe git is trying to use some overflow $TMPDIR

Comment: The $TMPDIR variable is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you ran out of disk space. Delete some files and try again.

Comment: Disk usage
 
7%, 8.9 GB of 120 GB / 111.1 GB free

Answer (score 0):

`.git` directory usually consumes huge disk space. Try it in a small directory first to make sure your steps are correct.

Comment: Read the comment below regarding my free space. I don't think the .git directory consumes 111.1 GB of space.